# Pyspark DF with a list of dates (with PANDAS) from today BACK 1 year

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Morning All,

I am trying to create a Pyspark DF with a list of dates from today back 1 year.

So far I can get the list going fwd from today with this

```
import pandas as pd
dates = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=365).tolist()
dates = list(map(pd.Timestamp.to_pydatetime, dates))
dates_df = spark.createDataFrame(dates, T.TimestampType())
```

But it gives me

```
value
2018-08-01
2018-08-02
...  
2019-08-02
```

I tried

```
dates ['new_value'] = dates['value'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.DateOffset(years=1))
```

but no go ... what I really want is

```
value
2018-08-01
2018-07-31
...  
2017-07-21
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your **`pd.date_range`** to end on the current day, and keep your periods the same, then just reverse the Series:

```
dates = pd.date_range(end=pd.datetime.today(), periods=365).tolist()[::-1]
```

Output:

```
[Timestamp('2018-07-31 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-30 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-29 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-28 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2018-07-27 23:06:54.977885', freq='D')
...
 Timestamp('2017-08-05 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-04 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-03 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-02 23:06:54.977885', freq='D'),
 Timestamp('2017-08-01 23:06:54.977885', freq='D')]
```